# fql OR and order by desc with offset

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have some issue with a Facebook's fql request :).

When I request like this

> SELECT uid, profile_url
>   FROM user where contains('potatoe') OR uid in(select id from profile where contains ('potatoe'))
>   ORDER BY mutual_friend_count desc LIMIT 0,2

I have always the same results, even if I change the offset...

But

- If I change DESC to ASC the "offset" works...
- If I change OR to AND
  and let the order by desc => the "offset" works too!

Something is wrong with my OR/desc/offset combo?
Or I just have misunderstood something with "or" operators? :/

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your FQL query like that:

> SELECT uid, profile_url 
>   FROM user
>
> where 
>   uid in(select uid from user where contains ('potatoe')  )
>
> > OR  uid in(
> >               select id from profile where contains ('potatoe')
> >               )
>
> ORDER BY mutual_friend_count desc
>
> LIMIT 0,2

FQL couldn't interpret in boolean expression the result of "contains", so your OR operator failed here...

Comment: Thanks! Works! But.. Why?
Still the same question... if "or" failed why I have results, and just the offset fail? 
Ok maybe "Or" fail with "contains" so :
- Why when I do this with "order by asc" it works?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your query is asking the same question two different ways:

- Show me all my friends user profiles that contain 'potatoe' **OR**
- Show me all profiles that belong to users who are my friends that contain 'potatoe'.

Simplify your query to this and see if it works as expected.

```
SELECT uid, profile_url FROM user WHERE contains('potatoe')
   ORDER BY mutual_friend_count DESC LIMIT 0,2
```

Comment: Well it's not really the same results. When you try with my query you have "karim.potatoes.1" but with your query he's not in my results...
That's why I use "OR" operator, in order to have more results ;)